# display html formatted content in td tag without html tags

Tags: php, html

```
<div align="center">
   <span style="COLOR: #9370db; FONT-SIZE: 14pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">120 Pro Palette Full Color Eye Shadow Fashion Eyeshadow
   </span>
</div>
```

i want to display this data in "td" tag but without tags like span, div, font, etc. display only formatted tasks.

data is comming from database.

Answer (score 0):

With a piece of css, will help you display that formatted text

```
<td stlye="text-align:center; COLOR: #9370db; FONT-SIZE: 14pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold ">
120 Pro Palette Full Color Eye Shadow Fashion Eyeshadow
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` property to do this. Here is some code you can try:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("YourTDId");

elem.innerHTML="<div>Example</div>";
```

This will help you put HTML directly into the td (give it an Id). You can also put normal text instead of HTML there.

```
elem.innerHTML="Non HTML Text";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No. This is not done in php. This is javascript. I'm sure you're confused there between php and javascript. Tell the exact scenario so that you can get better help.